# current bar_index has the pivothigh or not?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to know whether the current bar_index has the pivothigh or not?
In pine script, when each bar is being executed or processed individually, I wanted to find if that particular bar is pivothigh or not

```
leftBars = input(2)
rightBars=input(2)
ph = ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
```

with pivotcode() function, I can only get to know the pivothigh
when the current bar_index is 2 bars after pivothigh bar

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is "pivot" for you? On what basis is a bar pivot high? I suggest you try out a "Zig Zag" indicator in TradingView first. The built-in "Zig Zag" (unfortunatelly cannot link to it) of TradingView does exactly what you want if you extend the pivot calculation to the current bar.

Comment: @elod008 It is important to note that the Zig Zag indicator repaints. He will have bunch of issues if he doesn't wait for confirmation.

Comment: You have to wait a few bars to confirm if a pivot is formed or not. That's the nature of pivot levels. There will always be some lag and you cannot catch this immediately.

Comment: Thank you @vitruvius for this note! You are absolutely right. I just assumed the question is referring to "if my current bar is the highest since last real pivot". Otherwise, like you point it out, it's not how pivots work. It's up to you, Saurav Satwik, what you want to do.